# OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow giving a user hasn't approved this consumer error

Tags: authentication, oauth

I have setup a connected app and want to use the OAuth JWT. Based on my understanding of the salesforce documentation only preauthorized client can use this flow to get an access token.

I have enabled "admin approved users are pre-authorized" setting in my connected and enabled certain profiles under this. the certificate and other settings required for this flow has been set up as well.

I still get the following error while trying to get an access token using the JWT token.

> { error_description: "user hasn't approved this consumer" error:
>   "invalid_grant" }

the grant_type is set to `"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"` and assertion: `"base64url-encoded JWT token"`

Appreciate any help to get this working!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. AND please "check" the best answer to your own questions. Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

Based from the salesforce documentation:

> The authorization server validates the JWT and issues an access_token
>   based upon prior approval of the application.

It means you have to authorize the application at least once.

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[clientId]&redirect_uri=[redirectUri]&response_type=code

You don't need to work on the redirectUri.

Comment: The client_id is the Salesforce Consumer Key for your app. The redirect_uri is the callback url from your app's OAuth settings within Salesforce. The redirect_uri used in the auth call must match a callback uri registered for your app but the uri does NOT have to work or do anything. Eg use https://foo.com in both places.

Comment: Of course, use [https://test.salesforce.com/...](https://test.salesforce.com) if you're in the test region.

Answer (score 3):

"user hasn't approved this consumer" This is a common error caused when the user doesn't have a prior refresh_token associated with him/her.

The solution is to perform an Autorization grant (Web Server flow or User-Agent Flow) at least once.

I wrote in detail about it; look **specifically at step #3** here - https://mannharleen.github.io/2020-03-03-salesforce-jwt/

That should solve the error.

Comment: I've followed your steps, got the one time approval, created jwt and on the step to obtain the access code using the JWT, I am recieving an error 
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "invalid client credentials"
}
this doesn't make sense, since according to Salesforce it means my client secret is wrong... but the one time authorization step went smoothly and that is the only time u need the secret....